# Display Rows only if group of rows' sum is greater then 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table like the one below. I would like to get this data to SSRS (Grouped by LineID and Product and Column as Hour) to show only those rows where HourCount > 0 for every LineID and Product.

```
LineID  Product Hour    HourCount
3   A   0   0
3   A   1   0
3   A   2   0
3   A   3   0
3   A   4   0
3   A   5   0
3   B   0   65
3   B   1   56
3   B   2   45
3   B   3   34
3   B   4   43
3   B   5   45
4   A   0   54
4   A   1   34
4   A   2   45
4   A   3   44
4   A   4   55
4   A   5   44
4   B   0   0
4   B   1   0
4   B   2   0
4   B   3   0
4   B   4   0
4   B   5   0
5   A   0   45
5   A   1   77
5   A   2   66
5   A   3   55
5   A   4   0
5   A   5   0
5   B   0   0
5   B   1   0
5   B   2   45
5   B   3   0
5   B   4   0
5   B   5   0
```

Basically I would like this table to look like this before it's in SSRS:

```
LineID  Product Hour    HourCount
3   B   0   65
3   B   1   56
3   B   2   45
3   B   3   34
3   B   4   43
3   B   5   45
4   A   0   54
4   A   1   34
4   A   2   45
4   A   3   44
4   A   4   55
4   A   5   44
5   A   0   45
5   A   1   77
5   A   2   66
5   A   3   55
5   A   4   0
5   A   5   0
5   B   0   0
5   B   1   0
5   B   2   45
5   B   3   0
5   B   4   0
5   B   5   0
```

So display Product for the line only if any of the Hourd have HourCount higher then 0.

Is there any query that could give me these results or I should play with display settings in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with NonZero as
(
  select *
    , GroupZeroCount = sum(HourCount) over (partition by LineID, Product)
  from HourTable
)
select LineID
  , Product
  , [Hour]
  , HourCount
from NonZero
where GroupZeroCount > 0
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba570/1).

You could certainly so something similar in SSRS, but it's certainly much easier and intuitive to apply at the T-SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT LineID,Product,Hour,Count(Hour) AS   HourCount 
    FROM abc   
    GROUP BY LineID,Productm,Hour   HAVING Count(Hour) > 0
```